# serialize value in array

Tags: php, serialization

I am trying to post serialize value to an array, is it possible.. check following...

```
$product = serialize($_POST['product']);
$values = array('name'=>$_POST['name'], 'product'=>$product); 
print_r($values);
```

please let me know your suggestion to achieve this. thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I am confused....

Comment: There's no problem with the above code. What issue are you having?

Comment: @Byron Whitlock I have method AddProduct($data) in my products.class so i want to pass $data after getting it from form. i hope you got idea.

Comment: my question is just to check if i am using right approach?

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem, i have used '' instead of "" for serialized data and it worked. thanks.